# TypeScript: remap union type with values from object type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to remap typescript union type with values form object type?

e.g. what I have in mid:

```
type Union = 'item-type' | 'category';
type Special = {
    'item-type': 'itemType';
};

type RemapedValue = [... some realy awesome typescript ...] // => 'itemType' | 'category'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to write as clear as possible. It is like a hack, but does the job I think.

```
type Union = 'item-type' | 'category' | "test2" | "test-3";
type Special = {
    'item-type': 'itemType';
    'test-3': "test";
};

type UnionExtra = Special & {
    [P in Union]: P
};

type Outersect = {
    [P in keyof UnionExtra]: UnionExtra[P]
}[Union]

type Innersect = {
    [P in (Union & keyof Special)]: Special[P]
}[keyof Special]

type Result = Outersect | Innersect;
```

Comment: Is it possible to make that object key value from `type Special` would not be mandatory in `type Union`? e.g. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigcgcCBbAWlEkygB8sBjAQ1wHMkAnEUigIlwGdgAmNgbgBQxaAGVIlBNQA26KAG9BUZVhz4i4CJgBcq3HgAqmzEJVYuwAgGYdUDhG4DBAXyHDNsRCgCiAD2CM1HLiEJIyUABkCkoqANoAClAIqPDIcAC6uvEubiJQAPIArriMnKHAcopmCUmoANYQIEgAZp5pfgHUmW0+-oEJ6S6xqSiD7pBQAJJwcBCl5ZUxyjXJUAAUI6hRDU2tIWHSAJTd+1LSA0M7LVCnMmN5AEoOhdIVGEUlZZQVFNOz899+FAAPTAqAQXwSXAAEygjGer3QAD49PgjCRyFRaBAGMxWHYLHxBEA)

Comment: Try this [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigcgcCBbAWlEkygB8sBjAQ1wHMkAnEUigIlwGdgAmN8qBwjcALGwDcAKGLQAypEoJqAG3RQA3pKjasOfEXARMALl248AFUOYpOrF2AEAzCcEOJWnZgcERJ78LAfpIAvlLShrCIKACiAB7AjNRq8hCKKlAAZBqe2gDaAApQCKjwyHAAuqYFoeEyUADyAK64jJxpwGqadoXFqADWECBIAGZR5fGJ1FXjsQlJhRWheWUoSxGQUACScHAQbR0pCkrKeYPDY906vSVQABSrqNnno1Cp6coAlDPvJ4uh63qACVhE1lJ0MM1Wu1KJ0KDs9gdYVIgA)